# Dynamic list that automatically expands

Tags: python, pop-11

How can I make a Python equivalent of **pdtolist** from Pop-11?

Assume I have a generator called **g** that returns (say) integers one at a time.  I'd like to construct a list **a** that grows automatically as I ask for values beyond the current end of the list.  For example:

```
print a # => [ 0, 1, 2, g]
print a[0] # => 0
print a[1] # => 1
print a[2] # => 2
# (obvious enough up to here)

print a[6] # => 6
print a # => [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, g]
# list has automatically expanded

a = a[4:] # discard some previous values
print a # => [ 4, 5, 6, g]
print a[0] # => 4
```

Terminology - to anticipate a likely misunderstanding: a list is a "dynamic array" but that's not what I mean; I'd like a "dynamic list" in a more abstract sense.

To explain the motivation better, suppose you have 999999999 items to process. Trying to fit all those into memory (in a normal list) all at once would be a challenge. A generator solves that part of the problem by presenting them one at a time; each one created on demand or read individually from disk. But suppose during processing you want to refer to some recent values, not just the current one? You could remember the last (say) ten values in a separate list. But a dynamic list is better, as it remembers them automatically.

Comment: Override the list's `__getitem__` method to catch the `IndexError`.

Comment: So you have list `L` and perform `L[999999999]` - the list should become that length?

Comment: Yes, in principle.  Caveat programmor!

Comment: And with what fill values for instance?

Comment: Perhaps I should explain the motivation better. Suppose you did have 999999999 items to process. Trying to fit all those into memory (in a normal list) all at once would be a challenge. A generator solves that part of the problem by presenting them one at a time; each one created on demand or read individually from disk or whatever. But suppose during processing you want to refer to some recent values, not just the current one? You could remember the last (say) ten values in a separate list. But a dynamic list is better, as it remembers automatically.

Comment: updated my answer. Hope it works better for you

Comment: The `isinstance(index, slice)` fails to work for me (Python 2.6), which I why I had to use `__getslice__()`.  I notice `isinstance` is [considered harmful](http://www.canonical.org/~kragen/isinstance/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to all who contributed ideas!  Here's what I have gathered together from all the responses.  This retains most functionality from the normal list class, adding additional behaviours where necessary to meet additional requirements.

```
class DynamicList(list):
    def __init__(self, gen):
        self.gen = gen

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        while index >= len(self):
            self.append(next(self.gen))
        return super(DynamicList, self).__getitem__(index)

    def __getslice__(self, start, stop):
        # treat request for "last" item as "most recently fetched"
        if stop == 2147483647: stop = len(self)
        while stop >  len(self):
            self.append(next(self.gen))
        return super(DynamicList, self).__getslice__(start, stop)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        n = next(self.gen)
        self.append(n)
        return n

a = DynamicList(iter(xrange(10)))
```

Previously generated values can be accessed individually as items or slices.  The recorded history expands as necessary if the requested item(s) are beyond the current end of the list.  The entire recorded history can be accessed all at once, using `print a`, or assigned to a normal list using `b = a[:]`.  A slice of the recorded history can be deleted using `del a[0:4]`.  You can iterate over the whole list using `for`, deleting as you go, or whenever it suits.  Should you reach the end of the generated values, `StopIteration` is raised.

Some awkwardness remains.  Assignments like `a = a[0:4]` successfully truncate the history, but the resulting list no longer auto-expands.  Instead use `del a[0:4]` to retain the automatic growth properties.  Also, I'm not completely happy with having to recognise a magic value, `2147483647`, representing the most recent item.

Answer (score 2):

This might get you started:

```
class DynamicList(list):
    def __init__(self, gen):
        self._gen = gen

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        while index >= len(self):
            self.append(next(self._gen))
        return super(DynamicList, self).__getitem__(index)
```

You'll need to add some special handling for slices (currently, they just return a normal list, so you lose the dynamic behavior). Also, if you want the generator itself to be a list item, that'll add a bit of complexity.

Comment: This shouldn't be a list subclass; the `__init__` is incompatible and it shouldn't support `__len__` or `__setitem__`...

Comment: @agf: The `__init__` problem is a valid point, but why should it not support `__len__` or `__setitem__`?

Comment: Its length is unknown because the length of the generator is unknown, and it should only reflect items from the generator, so you shouldn't be able to assign to it.

Comment: @agf: A _generator's_ length is unknown, yes. But the dynamic list != the generator. Getting the length so far might not be terribly useful all the time, but can you give an example where it would be detrimental?

Comment: In my view `__len__` should return the current length of the expanded items, not including those already discarded and not including those still to come.

Answer (score 2):

Just answered another similar question and decided to update my answer for you
hows this?

```
class dynamic_list(list):
    def __init__(self,num_gen):
        self._num_gen = num_gen
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        if isinstance(index, int):
            self.expandfor(index)
            return super(dynamic_list,self).__getitem__(index)

        elif isinstance(index, slice):
            if index.stop<index.start:
                return super(dynamic_list,self).__getitem__(index)
            else:
                self.expandfor(index.stop if abs(index.stop)>abs(index.start) else index.start)
            return super(dynamic_list,self).__getitem__(index)

    def __setitem__(self,index,value):
        if isinstance(index, int):
            self.expandfor(index)
            return super(dynamic_list,self).__setitem__(index,value)

        elif isinstance(index, slice):
            if index.stop<index.start:
                return super(dynamic_list,self).__setitem__(index,value)
            else:
                self.expandfor(index.stop if abs(index.stop)>abs(index.start) else index.start)
            return super(dynamic_list,self).__setitem__(index,value)

    def expandfor(self,index):
            rng = []
            if abs(index)>len(self)-1:
                if index<0:
                    rng = xrange(abs(index)-len(self))
                else:
                    rng = xrange(abs(index)-len(self)+1)
            for i in rng:
                self.append(self._num_gen.next())
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this thread; it helped me solve my own problem. Mine was a bit simpler: I wanted a list that automatically extended if indexed past its current length --> allow reading and writing past current length. If reading past current length, return 0 values.
Maybe this helps someone:

```
class DynamicList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        self.expand(idx)
        return super().__getitem__(idx)

    def __setitem__(self, idx, val):
        self.expand(idx)
        return super().__setitem__(idx, val)

    def expand(self, idx):
        if isinstance(idx, int):
            idx += 1
        elif isinstance(idx, slice):
            idx = max(idx.start, idx.stop)

        if idx > len(self):
            self.extend([0] * (idx - len(self)))
```