# Is there a way to set index 1 in a list when index 0 hasnt been defined

Tags: python, list, jvm, bytecode

In Java ByteCode there is an opcode called "istore_1", which stores the top value of the stack into index 1 of the local variables, a list. I am trying to replicate this in python, but if you set index 1 of an empty list, its gonna set index 0 rather than index 1. My idea was to check if the first index of the list is empty, and if it is set it to like "emptyindex" or something, but after I did some research, I didnt find a way to check if an index is empty. My question is now how to store a value into index 1 of a list, even if index 0 hasnt been set, and set index 0 to "emptyindex" as a placeholder. Thanks a lot :D

```py
local_variables = []
stack = [1]

user = input("Enter instruction")
if user == "istore_1":
  local_variables.insert(1, stack[0])
print(local_variables)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: local_variables.insert(1, 5) Outputs: [5] What I want it to output: [empty or placeholder, 5]

Comment: Sorry, please update [your](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60990388/edit) question with actual python code that I can run.

Comment: There you go...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic list that automatically expands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265282/dynamic-list-that-automatically-expands)

Comment: No, Im trying to get the values leading up to the index to be empty, unless already set

Comment: "In Java ByteCode there is an opcode called "istore_1", which stores the top value of the stack into index 1 of the local variables, a list. "   This is not at all what `istore_1` does. `istore_*` instructions stores values into the local variable array which is not related to python lists.

Comment: There is no way to omit some index in the list, because they created by Py automatically. You could use dictionaries in case your indexes will not ever be repeated or use list and just append None to some index and it will be a sign for you in the further work with this list.  How about that?

Comment: Thats not an option, since there is a chance the first index is already written, in this case I dont wanna do anything, just if it is empty, I wanna fill up the empty space, so my value actually gets stored in index 1

Comment: Also, @PiRocks what do you not understand? I know the local variable array is not related to python lists, I am just trying to replicate it

Comment: @Darki write your replies with @ if you want people to see you've left comment for them

Comment: @Darki I see, when I first read your question it seemed like you where using something like Jython and where confused between the variable array and python lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function to manipulate your list:

```
def expand(a_list, index, value, empty=None):
    l = len(a_list)
    if index >= l:
        a_list.extend([empty]*(index + 1 - l))
    a_list[index] = value


local_variables = []

expand(local_variables, 1, 'str')

print(local_variables)
```

Output:

```
[None, 'str']
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java bytecode, method headers contain a field which gives the maximum size of the local variable table that method uses. So you can just predeclare a list like `[None] * MAX_LOCALS`. Or you can just do `[None] * 65535`, since that's the maximum possible local variable table size. Or you can just use a dictionary so you don't have to worry about unset indexes entirely.